# Why -1 is internally represented as all 1's

Tags: c, integer, negative-number

Why is -1 internally represented as all 1's in a 16 bit compiler?
This was used to solve the following program:

```
main()
{
    printf("%x",-1<<4);
}
```

I didn't understand the solution to this question.Please help.
Thank you :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: To add a little more to OldProgrammer's link, internally using two's complement to store negative numbers makes the hardware used to add and subtract both positive and negative numbers much simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code posted is also a poor example. **C11 6.5.7p4** "The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1 × 2^E2`, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1 × 2^E2` is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, **the behavior is undefined**." Your `E1` is negative. Left shifting is UB.

Answer (score 3):

Signed integers are represented as "two's complement".

When a number is positive, you will have its representation in binary as you expect.

When it's negative, it is being representd as two's complement.
The two's complement of k, where k has N bits, is 2^N-k. Since 2^N is a one bit followed by k-1 zeros,
you have, for example,

k = -3

N =  4  (4 bits, 2^N=16)

then -3 is represented as

`16 - 3 = 13`, which in binary is `1101`.

You can then see that -1 is represented as

`16 - 1 = 15`, which in binary is `1111`

So, if the internal representation is two's complement, the number -1 will always be represented as a sequence of ones.

The table below shows the representation of integers with 4 bits. Negatives are represented as two's complements.

```
REPR   N
----  --
0111   7
0110   6
0101   5
0100   4
0011   3
0010   2
0001   1
0000   0
1111  -1
1110  -2
1101  -3
1100  -4
1011  -5
1010  -6
1001  -7
1000  -8
```

If you were using one's complement, then you'd have three bits for the number and one for the sign,
so the table would be

```
REPR   N
----  --
0111   7
0110   6
0101   5
0100   4
0011   3
0010   2
0001   1
0000   0
1000   0
1001  -1
1010  -2
1011  -3
1100  -4
1101  -5
1110  -6
1111  -7
```

Why do we use 2's complement? Well, see that with one's complement you have two representations for zero (and we don't, in 2's complement). Besides that, you can add numbers (negative or positive) in two's complement and the result will just be correct.

One disadvantage of using two's complement is that you cannot represent `abs(INT_MIN)`.

More about two's complement in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: Nice to point out another form like "one's complement". +1.  Of course "one's complement" and "sign magnitude" don't have that pesky `abs(INT_MIN)` problem like  "two's complement".

Answer (score 1):

Signed binary numbers use what's called a Two's Complement. Check out the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement
If it helps, think of it as representing -65536 + x.

Answer (score 1):

Two's complement representation of `signed int x`:

- If the most significant bit of `x` is 0, then just take the the value represented by `x` "as is".
- If the most significant bit of `x` is 1, then calculate the value represented by `x` as follows:

  - Flip all the bits
  - Add 1 to the result
  - Consider the result as negative

Answer (score 1):

-1 is stored as all 1's because it is in Two's Complement notation.

Two's complement notation is used for a variety of reasons, some of which include:

- No special logic needed when dealing with negative numbers
- No wasted bits (positive 0 and negative 0)